# How to show data pointed to by a pointer in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I was wondering if there is any feature in Visual Studio 2008 that would show me data stored at address XY? Specifically I need to check data the pointer points to. Something like this:

```
BYTE *pMem = (BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, FileSize);
<do some magic at pMem+offset1>
//bug occurs, need to check data at pMem+offset2>
```

Basicly the "Locals" window shows me only first few bytes of the *pMem while I need to see 100th byte for example.

Of course I can store it in some another variable and check it when the execution hits the breakpoint but thats not as much handy/quick as looking at some window or writing some command somewhere in special console while the app is paused.

Thanks for any info.

Kra

P.S. its C++, not managed code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a memory Window (Debug | Windows | Memory) of which there are four to look at four different areas of memory.

Enter the address or expression that gives the address and you'll see the memory. VS will highlight the changes as you step through code).

Comment: Ahh, so its called a Memory Window. Thanks. It was missing in the menu but "Reset all settings" did the trick. Thanks!